# Twig - Fill a table horizontally with HTML2PDF

Tags: twig, pdf-generation, html-table, symfony

I'm working on filling a table horizontally in Twig and transform this twig view into a PDF.

I succeeded in filling it horizontally but I have an annoying problem remaining : I have a black line on the right of the last page of my resulting PDF.

Here's an picture of the problem in the PDF :

[image: PDF]

In Twig view :

[image: Twig]

Here's my code :

```
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Numéro</th>
    <th>Note</th>
    <th>Classement</th>
    <th class="espace"></th>
    <th>Numéro</th>
    <th>Note</th>
    <th>Classement</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for passercolle in passercolles %}

    {% if (loop.index is odd)  or loop.first %}
        <tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.index is odd %}
        <td>{{ passercolle.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ passercolle.note }}/20</td>
        <td>{{ passercolle.classement }}</td>
        <td class="espace" ></td>
    {% elseif loop.index is even %}
        <td>{{ passercolle.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ passercolle.note }}/20</td>
        <td>{{ passercolle.classement }}</td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.last and loop.last is odd %}
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if  (loop.index is even)  or loop.last %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I think it's a problem with loop.last but I can't solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing `{% if loop.last and loop.last is odd %}` by `{% if loop.last and passercolles|length is odd %}`